# jquery and ajax controls in asp.net clash on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

i am working on this asp.net project where i have created this tab using divs and what I've done is on a tab click show a div  and then on another, hide a div.
Now I've placed a form in both divs and hidden them using jQuery.
I have also used **updatepanel**  so that on asp.net button click the page does not  refresh.
Now when i click the tab of second button to say insert something, the content which was hidden in first div shows up too.
Please help me.
thanks.

Here is the page

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
        }

        #container {
            width: 670px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-color: white;
        }

        #firstTab, #secondTab {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: crimson;
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin-left: 11px;
            color: white;
        }

        #innerContainer {
            float: left;
            clear: left;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#secondContent').hide();

            $('#firstTab').click(function () {
                $('#secondContent').hide();
                $('#firstContent').show();

            });
            $('#secondTab').click(function () {
                $('#secondContent').show();
                $('#firstContent').hide();

            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="firstTab">First</div>
            <div id="secondTab">Second Tab</div>
            <div id="innerContainer">
                <span id="firstContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, quas, itaque, eveniet beatae optio magni nobis repellendus numquam aperiam ea ut nam molestias temporibus sed porro minima ipsa? Libero, maiores, qui consequatur fugiat et asperiores neque quos velit repellendus cupiditate molestiae iure doloremque architecto corporis accusamus ullam omnis suscipit doloribus laudantium maxime commodi provident dignissimos sapiente veritatis tenetur ad error facere reiciendis dolores officiis! Voluptatem, explicabo, necessitatibus quisquam minus maiores repudiandae nobis minima saepe id fugit ullam similique dolor iste! Minima, quisquam, molestias, facere ea asperiores itaque voluptatum doloribus sapiente facilis illo repellat veritatis minus et labore mollitia qui ducimus.
                </span>

                <span id="secondContent">Second Content here it goes.
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="editButton" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Insert Values" OnClick="editButton_Click" />

                </span>
            </div>
                    </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>






    </form>
</body>
```

And here is the c# Code

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "22";
        TextBox2.Text = "33";
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably would be a lot easier to answer this question if you would post your relevant code. Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: ok ill do that. give me some time.

Comment: This sounds similar to a question I answered: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752745/div-is-hidden-after-submit-in-updatepanel/20752889#20752889